# Proxyquire: Cannot Stub fs.readFileSync

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon, proxyquire

I seem unable to stub readFileSync on fs from the NodeJS core.  The following code isolates the issue.  Running the test via Mocha results in the following:

```
> mocha tests/test.js

      Some description
        1) "before all" hook


      0 passing (15ms)
      1 failing

      1) Some description "before all" hook:
         TypeError: Cannot read property 'charCodeAt' of undefined
          at Object.stripBOM (internal/module.js:48:14)
          at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) (node_modules/proxyquire/lib/proxyquire.js:276:43)
          at Proxyquire._withoutCache (node_modules/proxyquire/lib/proxyquire.js:179:12)
          at Proxyquire.load (node_modules/proxyquire/lib/proxyquire.js:136:15)
          at Context.<anonymous> (tests/test.js:12:15)
```

Here's tests/test.js

```
var proxyquire = require('proxyquire'),
    sinon = require('sinon'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    sut;

describe('Some description', function () {
    var readFileSyncStub;

    before(function () {
        readFileSyncStub = sinon.stub(fs, 'readFileSync');
        readFileSyncStub.withArgs('someFile.js', { encoding: 'utf8' }).returns('some text');
        sut = proxyquire('../sut', { fs: { readFileSync: readFileSyncStub } }); // Exception encountered somewhere in here ...
    });

    after(function () {
        fs.readFileSync.restore(); // This is executed ...
    });

    it('Some it', function () {
        // This never happens ...
    });
});
```

And here's sut.js, which is the module being tested:

```
var fs = require('fs'); // The code in this file is never executed ...

module.exports = function () {
    return fs.readFileSync('someFile.js', { encoding: 'utf8' });
};
```

The folder structure for the project is:

```
./sut.js
./package.json
./tests/test.js
```

test.js can be run by executing `mocha tests/test.js` from the prompt.

I noticed that several years ago there was an issue reported on Github about something that looks similar, but I can't tell if it's the same issue, or a different one.  Here's the link:

https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire/issues/12

In case it helps, these are the dependencies in my package.json file.  I tried using similar versions to the dependencies for proxyquire:

```
{
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "jshint": "^2.9.5",
    "jslint": "^0.11.0",
    "mocha": "~3.1",
    "proxyquire": "^1.8.0",
    "sinon": "~1.9"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
  ...
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to stub `fs.readFileSync()` if you're *also* using `proxyquire` to replace it (in fact, stubbing `fs.readFileSync()` is causing your problem, because it's breaking both `require()` and `proxyquire`).

Try this:

```
describe('Some description', function () {
  var readFileSyncStub;

  before(function() {
    readFileSyncStub = sinon.stub()
                            .withArgs('someFile.js', { encoding: 'utf8' })
                            .returns('some text');
    sut = proxyquire('../sut', { fs : { readFileSync : readFileSyncStub } });                         
  });

  it('Some it', function () {
    let value = sut();
    assert.equal(value, 'some text');
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks @robertklep, that works great!  I'm a little confused, though.  The examples on Github are stubbing the methods for fs:  https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire/blob/master/examples/sinon/foo-tests.js.

Comment: @Andrew those examples are old (5 years for that particular file). I guess that in the meantime, Node.js internals have changed. Merely stubbing `fs.readFileSync()` causes things to break in recent Node.js versions.

Comment: how will I be able to assert that readFileSyncStub was called in this case ?  Can I do sinon.assert.calledOnce or sinon.assert.calledExactly with on readFileSyncStub ?

Comment: @Novice did you try? ;D